# How to add custom dropdown template for typeahead?

Tags: angular

I'm looking for typeahead where I can add custom html using this parameter **typeahead-template-url**.
I couldn't find the same implemention for http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/index-bs4.html#typeahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular2 are not planning to provide template-urls stuff like it was in ng1
(loading html via http) but
you always can customize any component by inheriting
and replacing html and selector for component

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question's detail, but for question's title you should check out **ng2-bootstrap** being developed for **Angular2**.

- http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/index-bs4.html